# Bash scripting, multiple conditions in while loop

Tags: bash, shell, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to get a simple while loop working in bash that uses two conditions, but after trying many different syntax from various forums, I can't stop throwing an error. Here is what I have:

```
while [ $stats -gt 300 ] -o [ $stats -eq 0 ]
```

I have also tried:

```
while [[ $stats -gt 300 ] || [ $stats -eq 0 ]]
```

... as well as several others constructs. I want this loop to continue while `$stats is > 300` or if `$stats = 0`.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

The correct options are (in increasing order of recommendation):

```
# Single POSIX test command with -o operator (not recommended anymore).
# Quotes strongly recommended to guard against empty or undefined variables.
while [ "$stats" -gt 300 -o "$stats" -eq 0 ]

# Two POSIX test commands joined in a list with ||.
# Quotes strongly recommended to guard against empty or undefined variables.
while [ "$stats" -gt 300 ] || [ "$stats" -eq 0 ]

# Two bash conditional expressions joined in a list with ||.
while [[ $stats -gt 300 ]] || [[ $stats -eq 0 ]]

# A single bash conditional expression with the || operator.
while [[ $stats -gt 300 || $stats -eq 0 ]]

# Two bash arithmetic expressions joined in a list with ||.
# $ optional, as a string can only be interpreted as a variable
while (( stats > 300 )) || (( stats == 0 ))

# And finally, a single bash arithmetic expression with the || operator.
# $ optional, as a string can only be interpreted as a variable
while (( stats > 300 || stats == 0 ))
```

Some notes:

1. Quoting the parameter expansions inside `[[ ... ]]` and `((...))` is optional; if the variable is not set, `-gt` and `-eq` will assume a value of 0.
2. Using `$` is optional inside `(( ... ))`, but using it can help avoid unintentional errors. If `stats` isn't set, then `(( stats > 300 ))` will assume `stats == 0`, but `(( $stats > 300 ))` will produce a syntax error.

Comment: Bravo. a classic way to answer a post. Well done.  I'm assuming you can use the same syntax with `until` as well, yes?

Comment: @SaxDaddy More or less, as long as you take care to negate the conditions correctly: `while [ foo -o bar ]` becomes `until ! [ foo -o bar ]`, but `while foo || bar` becomes `until ! foo && ! bar`.

Comment: Seems this does not work when reading incoming data: `while [[ read -r line && $inputdata != "" ]]; do`. How do I achieve that?

Comment: When reading incoming data you can for example use this form for multiple conditions:

`while read -r theline && [ "$theline" != "" ]`

Comment: @chepner could you please help me with my condition: `while [[ $counter -le 97 -a "$breakCond" -le "$Mu"]]`

Comment: `-a` is not recognized inside `[[...]]`; use `&&`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
while [ $stats -gt 300 -o $stats -eq 0 ]
```

`[` is a call to `test`. It is not just for grouping, like parentheses in other languages. Check `man [` or `man test` for more information.

Comment: I recommend `[[` over `[`. See my comment on the other answer.

Comment: That's fair. I used [ ] because that was what the OP was trying to use. I've seen both used with success.

Answer (score 0):

The extra [ ] on the outside of your second syntax are unnecessary, and possibly confusing.  You may use them, but if you must you need to have whitespace between them.

Alternatively:

```
while [ $stats -gt 300 ] || [ $stats -eq 0 ]
```

Comment: Actually, `[[` is generally the preferred built-in to introduce a test expression. It has several advantages over the older single `[` syntax.

Comment: @danfuzz I know this is an old thread, but it would be great if you cite this in case people wanna read exactly why [[ is preferred over [. I know everyone can Google on their own... but still, it's good practice to cite.. makes your comment more robust and the reader's search faster and more efficient.