# Bash shell script multiple tests in while condition

Tags: bash, while-loop, multiple-conditions

Firstly, yes I have read this:

[Bash scripting, multiple conditions in while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534595/bash-scripting-multiple-conditions-in-while-loop)

The answer is probably in that post but I'm failing to see it so I hope someone can help. I want to test for two conditions in my while loop, essentially I want to combine these two tests which are currently nested, one's just a regex, and the second is to test if it is actually a valid date:

```
while ! [[ "$searchDate" =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}$ ]]; do
    read -p "Enter date in format DDmmmYYYY: " searchDate

    while ! (date -d $searchDate); do
        read -p "That date doesn't appear to be valid, try again: " searchDate
    done
done
```

I feel like I should be able to write something like:

```
while [[ ! "$searchDate" =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}$ ]] || ( ! date -d $searchDate); do
    read -p "There's something funky about that date, try again: " searchDate
```

but I can't get it to work, I'm not sure if it's my logic that's skewiff, or the way I'm trying to combine the tests (or both!)...

Comment: `!` can only use used immediately after `if` or `while` you can't put it into a subshell by itself.

Comment: @Barmar you can put `!` in front of any (single or multistage) pipeline, including in front of a simple command in a subshell as shown here. It's not specific to `if` or `while` in any way.

Comment: That code in your comment doesn't assign to `searchDate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
while [[ ! "$searchDate" =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}$ ]] || ! date -d $searchDate; do
    read -p "Enter date in format DDmmmYYYY: " searchDate
done
```

Comment: There's no reason for the sub-shell around the `date` command.

Comment: Thanks, Yes very true, I had also realized that after posting but while debating another answer this change slipped my mind.