# Bash: How to read file in while loop containing multiple conditions?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

After reading a ton of documentation and multiple SO solutions, I still cannot get the right syntax for multiple conditions in a while loop with the read line command.

I tried the following stack overflow solution below to no avail.

[Bash scripting, multiple conditions in while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534595/bash-scripting-multiple-conditions-in-while-loop)

```
!/bin/bash

while (( $(read -r line) && "$1" != 1 ))
do
  #Do stuff
done < myFile.txt
```

The error I am getting is `((: && 8 != 1 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "&& 8 != 1 "`

Also tried `read -r line` instead of wrapping it in the `$` sign and still did not work.

Where did I go wrong?

EDIT: Ignore the logic of my original post.  That will eventually get changed.  I'm just trying to find out the proper syntax.

Comment: Why would the value of `$1` ever change here?

Comment: Shouldn't be `[ "$1" != "1" ]`?

Comment: Sorry guys.  Just ignore the logic inside the loop (or lack thereof).  I just wanted to know the syntax for a while loop using the read command with multiple conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the correct syntax here would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line && (( "$1" != 1 ))
do
    # some stuff
done < myFile.txt
```

The `read` command needs to go outside of the `(( ))` if you want the loop to run as long as `read` is successful. That said, I'm not sure about the conditions you're using, as `$1` is the first argument passed to your script, which won't ever change in the script you've shown us.

Comment: @TomFrench Thank you very much. See my edit regarding the logic of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of a `while` loop is `while compound_list do_group`<sup>[1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02)</sup>.

Where a `compound_list` is any valid sequence of commands basically.

Your current attempt is trying to stick commands/etc. *inside* an arithmetic expression which is why you are getting a syntax error. Neither of the bits of your `compound_list` are arithmetic expressions though (the second one could be but doesn't need to be).

So you want something more like this

```
while read -r line && [ "$1" != 1 ]
```

or to keep the arithmetic expression instead of the `[` like this

```
while read -r line && (( "$1" != 1 ))
```

That being said, and as Tom Fenech indicated in his comment on the post, nothing in the code you've shown us will ever cause the value of `$1` to change. So what exactly is that bit of the test supposed to be doing?

The problem you had following the advice in the answer you linked is that you didn't pay attention to where the various types of brackets/parentheses/etc. went and what they meant (the answer didn't explain them) and none of the conditions in that question were commands themselves.

Comment: Great answer, very comprehensive!

Comment: Sorry, ignore the logic regarding the loop.  I just came up with a crappy example to get the syntax down.