# Bash: How do I format these conditions in a while loop?

Tags: bash

How do I format the 2 conditions below into one while loop which should ensure that data enter contains at least one alphabetical character and doesn't already exist in the directory /dev/null.

1

```
#name = "test123"
read -p "Enter you name: " name
until [[ "$name" =~ [A-Za-z] ]]; do
    read -p "Please enter a valid name: " name
done
```

2

```
while id -u $name 2>/dev/null>1 ; do # Checks if username already exists
read -p "Please enter valid input: "
```

I know there are different ways toformat the 2 arguments in the while loop as it depends on the 2 arguments however i am not sure.

I've found this source below which i could proceed to trial an error however I want to know why I choosing to format the condition in such a way.

[Bash scripting, multiple conditions in while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534595/bash-scripting-multiple-conditions-in-while-loop)

Answer (score 2):

You can use your loop like this:

```
while read -r -p "Please enter valid input: " name; do
   [[ $name == *[a-zA-Z]* ]] && { id -u "$name" >/dev/null 2>&1 || break; }
done

echo "Got a good name: $name"
```

- `read` is used in a while loop which will keel looping until a `break` is executed inside the loop.
- `$name == *[a-zA-Z]*` will check for presence of an alphabet in input `name`. `*` is used for globbing on either side.
- `id -u` command will return `0` if entered name is found in user database and `break` gets executed when `id` command fails (username is unique).
- `>/dev/null 2>&1` is used to suppress stdout/stderr from `id` command since we only care about return status of `id`.

Comment: Could you please explain the chosen options for read and why you formatted it this way?

Comment: What do the asterisks do around the parentheses, why are you using double square brackets for one condition and curly ones for the next. Why have you included 'break'? (I know break ends the loop)

Comment: Why have you used this way: >/dev/null 2>&1

Comment: You've made reference to 'id -i' however in your example you've used 'id -u', furthermore doesn't the double pipe mean 'or'? What does the double pipe mean in this instance.

Comment: No problem :), what does the double pipe you've used do in this instance?

Comment: `||` is used for `OR` clause. So `break` executes when `id -u` returns non-zero status

Comment: Why is the while statement referenced after do?

Comment: `while [[ $name == *[a-zA-Z]* ]] && { id -u "$name" >/dev/null 2>&1 || break; }`; do <--- Something like this

Comment: You must have done some copy/paste error. Same code works fine on my bash shell. Make sure you're executing it using `bash`

Comment: I am executing in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php and it's not working.

Comment: What version of bash do you have? I got Bash 4+

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107771/discussion-between-pythontamer-and-anubhava).

Comment: This script also worked great on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php