# while loop error in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, centos7

I understand that this is not a duplicate post, since other posts, even though they have covered development patterns, have not dealt with the while clause precisely. There are many examples of using "if", but not "while".

I tried many codes, but my 'while' clause do not work correctly! :\

I am using: CentOS 7x (64-bit) and shell bash

```
#!/bin/bash
bkp="x"
while [[ "$bkp" != "Y" || "$bkp" != "y" || "$bkp" != "N" ]]
do
   echo $bkp
   read bkp
done
exit 0
```

When I run:

```
bash -x ./script
+ bkp=x
+ [[ x != \Y ]]
+ echo x
x
+ read bkp
```

I can't get out of while loop! :\
The while clause compare doesn't work!

I tried too:

```
#!/bin/bash
bkp="x"
while [[ "$bkp" != "Y" ]] || [[ "$bkp" != "y" ]]  || [[ "$bkp" != "N" ]]
do
   echo $bkp
   read bkp
done
exit 0
```

And

```
#!/bin/bash
bkp="x"
while [ "$bkp" != "Y" -o "$bkp" != "y"  -o "$bkp" != "N" ]
do
   echo $bkp
   read bkp
done
exit 0
```

Another example:

```
#!/bin/bash
bkp="x"
while [ $bkp != 'Y' -o $bkp != 'y'  -o $bkp != 'N' ]
do
   echo $bkp
   read bkp
done
exit 0
```

Another example:

```
#!/bin/bash
bkp="x"
while [[ $bkp != 'Y' ]] || [[ $bkp != 'y' ]] || [[ $bkp != 'N' ]]
do
   echo $bkp
   read bkp
done
exit 0
```

In the last case, when I run the script:

```
bash -x ./script 
+ bkp=x
+ '[' x '!=' Y -o x '!=' y -o x '!=' N ']'
+ echo x
x
+ read bkp
Y
+ '[' Y '!=' Y -o Y '!=' y -o Y '!=' N ']'
+ echo Y
Y
+ read bkp
y
+ '[' y '!=' Y -o y '!=' y -o y '!=' N ']'
+ echo y
y
+ read bkp
N
+ '[' N '!=' Y -o N '!=' y -o N '!=' N ']'
+ echo N
N
+ read bkp
```

I imagine that is a simple thing to fix my code, hehehe ...

Any idea?

Thanks,
Joca.

Comment: I'm assuming you want `while ! [[ $bkp = [YyNn] ]]; do read -r bkp; done`?

Comment: BTW, `-o` and `-a` are marked obsolescent in the POSIX test standard; search for `OB` in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: Or you want `[[ "$foo" != "A" && "$foo" != "B" ]]`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy

Thanks a lot for your answer, but more and less.

How do I compare two variables in the same while?

In your example, you compare values ​​of the same variable. How to compare var1 or var2 in the same while?

I had searched how to use where clause here in StackOverflow, and what I found was this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534595/bash-scripting-multiple-conditions-in-while-loop

Comment: kvantour,

Thanks a lot for your help too:

       #!/bin/bash
       foo="a"
       foo2="a"
       while [[ "$foo" != "A" || "$foo2" != "B" ]]
       do
            echo $foo ; echo $foo2
            read foo
            read foo2
      done
      exit 0

Is this! ;)

Comment: @Jocalinux The problem isn't what you're comparing, the problem is using local OR when you want logical AND. The results of combining negated tests can be counterintuitive; see [de Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).