# Writing a do while loop in bash with multiple conditions

Tags: bash, do-while

I'm having some trouble writing a do-while loop in bash with multiple conditions.

My code currently works when it is like this:

```
    while
    count=$((count+1))
    ( MyFunction $arg1 $arg2 -eq 1 )
    do
       :
    done
```

But I want to add a second condition to the "do-while" loop like so:

```
    while
    count=$((count+1))
    ( MyFunction $arg1 $arg2 -eq 1 ) || ( $count -lt 20 )
    do
       :
    done
```

When I do this I get an "command not found error".

I've been trying some of the while loop examples from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534595/bash-scripting-multiple-conditions-in-while-loop) post but had no luck and the do-while example I use is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489809/emulating-a-do-while-loop-in-bash). In particular the answer with 137 likes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(` is part of syntax and `$count` is not a valid command. The `test` or `[` is a valid command that is used to "test" expressions.

```
while
   count=$((count+1))
   [ "$(MyFunction "$arg1" "$arg2")" -eq 1 ] || [ "$count" -lt 20 ]
do
   :
done
```

The answer you mention uses arithmetic expressions with `((` (not a single `(`, but double `((` without anything between). You could also do:

```
while
   count=$((count+1))
   (( "$(MyFunction "$arg1" "$arg2")" == 1 || count < 20 ))
do
   :
done
```

Comment: I understand why this should work for me but I don't understand why I get a syntax error while using it. I get an error like: -eq 1 || count < 20 : syntax error in expression. It then mentions the error token being in my function, but it looks like the code runs through to completion.

Comment: Since `bash` is interpreted, parsing and evaluation/execution run somewhat in parallel. A syntax error becomes just another run-time error, and is interpreted as a failure, the same as if a command actually ran but had a non-zero exit status.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I've tried it again using your edit @chepner and it runs without the syntax error as well now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` loop:

```
for ((count=0; i<20 && $(MyFunction $arg1 $arg2) == 1; count++)); do
   echo $count
done
```